# Combining output from smatr with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset of leaf trait measurements made at multiple sites at two contrasting seasons.  I am interested to explore the association/line fit between a pair of traits and to differentiate the seasons at each site.

Rather than a linear regression, I would prefer to use the Standardised Major Axis approach within the smatr package:

```
e.g. sma.site1 <- sma(TraitA ~ TraitB * Visit, data=subset(myfile, Site=="Site1")) # testing the null hypothesis of common slopes for the two Visits (Seasons) at a given Site.
```

I can produce a handy lattice plot in ggplot2 with a separate panel for each Site and the points differentiated by Visit:

```
e.g. qplot(TraitB, TraitA, data=myfile, colour=Visit) +  facet_wrap(~Site, ncol=2)
```

However, if I add trend lines fitted with the additional argument in ggplot2:

```
+  geom_smooth(aes(group=Visit), method="lm", se=F)
```

……, those lines are not a good match for the sma coefficients.

What I would like to do is fit the lines suggested by the sma test onto the ggplot lattice.  Is there an easy, or efficient, way to do that?

I know that I can subset the data, produce a plot for each site, add the relevant lines with + geom_abline() and then stitch the separate plots up together with grid.arrange().  But that feels very long-winded.

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the `smatr` package but you should be able to tweak this to get the right values. Since you provided no data I used the leaf data from the example in the pkg. The basic idea is to pull out the slope & intercept from the returned `sma` object and then facet the `geom_abline`. I may be misinterpreting the object, though.

```
library(smatr)
library(ggplot2)

data(leaflife)

do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(leaflife$site), function(x) {
  obj <- sma(longev~lma*rain, data=subset(leaflife, site=x))
  data.frame(site=x, 
             intercept=obj$coef[[1]][1, 1],
             slope=obj$coef[[1]][2, 1])
})) -> fits

gg <- ggplot(leaflife) 
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=lma, y=longev, color=soilp))
gg <- gg + geom_abline(data=fits, aes(slope=slope, intercept=intercept))
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~site, ncol=2)
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, hrbrmstr - I think we're pretty close.  But the data-frame 'fits' now contains four identical rows of coefficients.  As a result a single line is then repeated on the four plots - not corresponding to the data points.  Each sma object provides a $groupsummary that should detail the relevant coefficients - in my case this will be grouped by Visit (a factor with two levels for any site e.g. Summer and Winter).  For some reason 'fits' seems to be locked on to the first site.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question and am not sure if you are still interested in this. I run the code by hrbrmstr, and found actually the only thing you need to change is:

```
obj <- sma(longev~lma*rain, data=subset(leaflife, site == x))
```

then you can get the plot with four lines for each group.

[image: a]

and also

[image: another example]